# reference a deployed contract in truffle or node.js

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle, nodejs

I have a previously deployed contract on my PRIVATE-NET which I know its address. Now I am using truffle. How do I reference this contract in truffle console using its address? I looked through web3.eth interfaces but cannot find a function which does this. The contract deployed is done using Mist, I tried use the contract name in Mist but truffle cannot find it.

Comment: Have you tried web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address) ?